# Python: Multiple printing in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have multiple address and settingname as shown in xml code below:

```
<Settings>
   <Setting>                  
      <Address>15:0</Address>
      <Comments />
      <Conditions />
      <IsSingleEnded>true</IsSingleEnded>
      <IsVisibilityExternal>false</IsVisibilityExternal>
      <MetaDatas />
      <SettingName>123</SettingName>
   </Setting>
   <Setting>                  
      <Address>18:0</Address>
      <Comments />
      <Conditions />
      <IsSingleEnded>true</IsSingleEnded>
      <IsVisibilityExternal>false</IsVisibilityExternal>
      <MetaDatas />
      <SettingName>abc</SettingName>
   </Setting>
</Settings>
```

I would like to print all the SettingName and Address.
Here is my code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('abc.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

    for name in tree.findall('.//SettingName'):
        for address in tree.findall('.//Address'):
            name1 = name.text
            address1 = address.text
            if name1 and address1:
                print name1, address1
```

In the end, it print multiple times of the settingname and address. What i want is one settingname have one address and it keep printing until finish printing all the settingname.
May i know how can i fix it through my code?

Comment: Is there a common parent element shared by `SettingName` and `Address`?

Comment: Show us the complete xml ( or atleast complete relevant, you would need to show the parent of these address and settingname) , maybe two or three such address/settingName would be good.

Comment: Just updated the xml file, they have a common parent element <Settings>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to get all the `Setting` nodes, and then iterate inside it to get each `SettingName` and `Address` node for each setting and print them. Example -

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('BXT_A0_RevF15.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

    for setting in tree.findall('.//Setting'):
        address = setting.find('./Address').text
        setting_name = setting.find('./SettingName').text
        if setting_name and address:
            print setting_name , address
```

---

If it is possible that some settings do not have `Address` or `SettingName` , then you would also need to account for those case by putting a `None` check. Example -

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('BXT_A0_RevF15.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

    for setting in tree.findall('.//Setting'):
        address = setting.find('./Address')
        setting_name = setting.find('./SettingName')
        if setting_name is not None and address is not None:
            print setting_name.text , address.text
```

Comment: having error SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element

Comment: the problem is solved. my mistake, typo. Thank you so much!